# Adding a second header row to bootstrap-vue's b-table

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a table header that looks like this:

[image: table header]

I'm trying to recreate this table in bootstrap-vue.  The raw HTML looks like this (simplified):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="4">Group 1</th>
      <th colspan="4">Group 2</th>
      <!--etc-->
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <th>Field</th>
      <th>Median</th>
      <!-- etc -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody><!-- actual data --></tbody>
</table>
```

The core b-table code will create the 2nd row easily/automatically.  I'm trying to figure out how to jam the 1st row in there.  As a little kicker, I need to be able to control the contents of the two group names (i.e. if they change a control somewhere, "Group 1" becomes "Group Foo").

I made a playground for anyone that needs a starting point for helping figure this out:  https://codesandbox.io/s/p56y3y2lnx  The goal in there would be to programmically add a 1st row that includes the `group1name` and spans the width of the table in one colspan.

Comment: One idea I had is to use an event (`@input`) on the b-table to inject the extra row... but it's pretty much anti-everything about Vue :)

Comment: uses [slot=top-row](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#custom-data-rendering) may be one option, like this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mz99wl1kwx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version v2.0.0-rc.14 (released 2019-03-08) you can now add additional rows above the header using the slot `thead-top`.

For your example, you would place the following code inside of the `b-table` tag:

```
  <template slot="thead-top" slot-scope="data">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="3">Group 1</th>
      <th colspan="4">Group 2</th>
      <th colspan="4"></th>
    </tr>
  </template>
```

Here's a reference to the new feature: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#adding-additional-rows-to-the-header

Comment: Thanks John, I think I actually [talked the author into adding this feature](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/2231) but am not able to update to that version yet... But going forward your solution is definitely right!.

Comment: @Ryley : Thank you for getting that feature added! I've used it now a couple of times.

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to find a clean way to achieve the results I wanted, so I ended up with something more hacky.

On `b-table` you can add an `input` event, so I did that to know when the table was finished loading.

HTML:

```
<b-table @input="tableLoaded" ref="table"></b-table>
```

then in my methods:

```
tableLoaded() {
    if (!this.$refs.table) {
        return;
    }

    var headers = this.$refs.table.$el.querySelectorAll('thead tr');
    if (headers.length > 1) {
        return;//nothing to do, header row already created
    }

    var topHeader = document.createElement('tr');
    topHeader.innerHTML =
        '<th></th>'+
        '<th colspan="3">Group 1</th>'+
        '<th colspan="4">Group 2</th>'+
        '<th colspan="4"></th>';
    headers[0].parentNode.insertBefore(topHeader, headers[0]);
}
```

I'd be happy to accept a cleaner solution.