# How to add rowspan and colspan in bootstrapvue tables?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

Is there any way to add rowspan and colspan in bootstrapvue (https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#table-colgroup)  tables .. Issue is already raised in github (https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/1726).. The documentation provides colgroup however I need to implement rowspan and colspan as we do usually in bootstrap table or raw table in html.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried the suggestion of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51504745/adding-a-second-header-row-to-bootstrap-vues-b-table?rq=1 , worked in basic header spanning however I really find it hard to match the spanned headers and the fields (data). For now, I use bootstrap4 to handle elements like table and I combine bootstrap and bootstrapvue.

Comment: Current bootstrap-vue library does not handle colspan & rowspan, and I don't think maintainer will work on it in the near future. I also desperately search for a better solution than pure bootstrap table.

Comment: yup, because its better if we can fully utilize bootstrap-vue rather than combining bootsrap that runs with jquery. Hoping for future developments

Comment: You can always render html table/tbody/tr using Bootstrap v4. classes. No need for jquery (table doesn't use it anyway).

Comment: howerver, I do not want to mix native bootstrap to the templates provided by bootstrap-vue (which is done via rows). But as I see today, they added more documentation with tables